# Stoi was not declared in scope - Code::blocks

Tags: c++, c++11

**Edit:** I'm trying to tell it to work with C++11 by clicking "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard" in the compiler flags.

I'm getting stoi was not declared in scope, and I've added c++11 to `Code::Blocks;` I've added compatibility in Settings -> Compilers -> Compiler flags, but it still keeps giving me that error.

And when I try to do atoi or strtol I get the following error:

> C:\Users\user\Desktop\Programming\NewProject\main.cpp|19|error: cannot
>   convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'const char*'
>   for argument '1' to 'long int strtol(const char*, char**, int)'|

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string numberGuessed;
    int numberGuessedint = 0;

    do {

        cout << "Guess a number between 1 and 10: ";
        getline(cin, numberGuessed);
        numberGuessedint = stoi(numberGuessed);
        cout << numberGuessedint << endl;


    } while(numberGuessedint != 4);

    cout << "You win!" << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Which compiler?  What is your actual command line for invoking the compiler?  (It looks like stoi is not being enabled properly).

Comment: Are you telling the compiler to use C++11 or later?  According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) the `stoi` is a C++11 feature.

Comment: I downloaded Code::Blocks with minGW built into it.  I'm trying to tell it to work with C++11 by clicking "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard" in the compiler flags.

Comment: Is there a Code::Blocks support website or mailing list?  I think you are going to do better there.

Comment: Thanks, I just posted there.  Hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a known bug in MinGW bundled with Code::Blocks.

You can apply a patch: http://tehsausage.com/mingw-to-string

Or download fresh version of MinGW (preferable with threading support, as you lack it too) and replace one you have right now.

Comment: I love you.  This isn't rhetorical, and it's not hyperbole.  It's pure, unconditional love.  <3

Answer (score 1):

To use `atoi` you need:

```
        numberGuessedint = atoi(numberGuessed.c_str());
```

Comment: But the question is about `stoi` not `atoi`.  Different first letters.  See [stoi at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: I was answering the part of the question about "And when I try to do atoi or strtol I get the following error:

C:\Users\user\Desktop\Programming\NewProject\main.cpp|19|error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'long int strtol(const char*, char**, int)'|"

Comment: @maazza: ... This isn't a question, it's a partial answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing a solution which worked for me. As I found in most of the solutions posted on stack overflow, code blocks earlier versions contain a bug. So I deleted my older code blocks version and installed a new version 17.12 from code blocks website.

Then I just clicked on "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard" in the compiler flags.

Settings -> Compilers -> Compiler flags.

It works for me(I am using windows 7).

Comment: without changing the codeblock version, just clicking the "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard" worked for me.