# Error: Function stoi Not Declared (-std=c++11 is Enabled)

Tags: string, c++11, sstream

I'm using **Code::Blocks 16.01** on **Windows 10**.

I need to convert a string to an integer.

So I'm trying to use `stoi`, but it says it's not declared.

I have enabled `-std=c++11` in compiler settings but it still gives me an error:

```
'stoi' was not declared in this scope
```

**Screenshot of Code::Blocks:**

[image: Screenshot of Code::Blocks]

**The part of the code which causes the error is:**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n,m,k;
    string nmk;
    ifstream test("input00.txt");
    if (test.is_open())
    {
        getline (test,nmk,' ');
        n = stoi (nmk,NULL,10);
        getline (test,nmk,' ');
        m = stoi (nmk,NULL,10);
        getline (test,nmk, '\n');
        k = stoi (nmk,NULL,10);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a [mcve]. You haven't shown any #include statements for example.

Comment: I'm a first time user of StackOverflow. Corrected the mistake.

Comment: That's better. Unfortunately it works fine for me (on gcc linux; I don't have codeblocks) once I add a final closing bracket so I don't know the answer, but hopefully someone else will

Comment: The code does run on visual studio 2017 but not on code blocks, if that helps!!

Comment: Don't use `using namespace std` because it pollutes the global namespace.  Instead use `std::stoi()`.  Switch to Visual Studio.  It's free and works.

Comment: I tried `std::stoi()`. It says std doesn't have member `stoi()`.

Comment: I'd guess that codeblocks just has an old enough version of gcc that it doesn't include the full c++11 library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stoi was not declared in scope - Code::blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243888/stoi-was-not-declared-in-scope-codeblocks)